# Can i redesign the bootstrap range datepicker to make use of inline calendars

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-5

I have a index.html file. I want to create a inline range calendar using bootstrap. But I am getting an error . I do not know good bootstrap, javascript. please help me

Comment: Hi @fj-tolu thanks if you can edit your post and include the code you are trying. It will always help people to work out an answer. And hey take a look at this :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: We aren't going to be able to help unless you provide a lot more information.  For starters, edit your question and please explain what you mean by "inline range calendar".  Show us the relevant code segments and explain at what part in that code you're getting the error, and give us the exact error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.